# How to arrange multiple files size into single HTML card?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I want to arrange multiple items **(photo/videos)** size in single HTML card like facebook or instagram:

[image: Example].

i want to know is there any kinds of library or javaScript code do what i have to do? i want the items auto arrange according to the size contain without extending the card size?

here is the source code of my layout..

```
<div class="panel-image">
    {% for i in object.filemodel_set.all %}
    <img src="{{i.file.url}}" alt="article" class="img-responsive card-img-top">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the bootstrap column class to set the image. You can have a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/neilhem/full/jlJHb/). Hope this solves your issue. Happy Coding!

Sample HTML Code :

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_24f47d4b53_h.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_24f47d4b53_h.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_24f47d4b53_h.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_24f47d4b53_h.jpg');"></div>
```

CSS Code :

```
.img {
margin-right: -15px; // Remove right gap
margin-left: -15px;  // Remove left gap
padding-bottom: 62.5%; // ratio is 16:10
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```